# Spring initializer Java version 15 is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use a spring initializer to create a spring project:

[image]

I want to create a project based on Java 15.

But I see only versions 17, 11, and 8.

Any idea why I don't see version 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea why I don't see version 15?

Because this is not a LTS java version. LTS means long time support.

> But I see only versions 17, 11, and 8

Because those are the LTS java versions provided by ORACLE.

[More about LTS java versions here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html)

It would make sense to deliver a spring project which is based on a long term supported JDK right? You could configure it otherwise but to officially deliver a product with a non long term supported JDK would not be a decision that most would make.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for Java 14, so I think it should work for 15. Be sure to test it before you start your project. Also this is for spring boot.
In your pom:

```
<properties>
 <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <release>15</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The question was why it wasn't on the initializr, not how to use it.